# "A numeric filter is not working with one index while is working with another same index. What could be the reason?"

Tags: redisearch

RediSearch Numeric filter stopped working suddenly for the one index in production. While its working in another same index in same server.

Schema is as provided below and I am trying to do filter on field ExpireAt

[image: Schema of Index]

I have already tried below queries. all providing 0 documents.

ft.search 9194_Cache "@ExpireAt:[0 inf]" Limit 0 2

ft.search 9194_Cache "@ExpireAt:[-1 inf]" Limit 0 2

ft.search 9194_Cache "@ExpireAt:[637024139268750000 637024139268750000]" Limit 0 2

------------Sample Data-Top 2 Records are like below--------
[image: Top 2 records]

Below query with result.

[image: Top 2 query]

While same is working for other index. check below result.
[image]

Comment: version : redis-cli 5.0.5

Comment: See discussion here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/redisearch/7Ev4rlDwYHU/LBx3MyHCBQAJ